# Асинхронная работа нескольких функций python

Tags: python, многопоточность, asyncio, multiprocessing

Есть три функции `A(a), B(b), C(c)`; Все функции имеют код:

```
def name(arg): # a или b или c вместо name
 while True():
  print(a) # a или b или c
```

Нужно сделать функции асинхронными без потери скорости (или минимальной), к примеру такие:

- Функция `A(a)` работает из файла `firstfunc.py`
- Функция `B(b)` работает из файла `secondfunc.py`
- Функция `C(c)` работает из файла `thirdfunc.py`

Как подобное реализовать лучше всего?

Comment: Запустить три разных процесса, три разных потока или три разных сопрограммы. Зависит от того, что именно делают ваши функции, какой ресурс является для них ограничивающим, взаимодействуют ли они друг с другом и, если да, то как.

Comment: Каждый процесс связан с главным - от туда я им передаю множество значений для дальнейшей работы. В это же время, эти процессы между собой никак не связаны; они не выполняют одинаковую работу, но работают с одной средой

Comment: Если они I/O bound и есть возможность использовать неблокирующися вызовы, то лучше использовать asyncio. Если нет такой возможности, то multithreading. Если CPU bound, то multiprocessing.

Comment: Асинхронность имеет смысл когда функция при своей работе чего то ждет, не задействуя при этом процессор. Обычно это ожидание сетевого ввода-вывода. В вашем случае print конечно пишет в stdout и если буфер переполнится его ядро приостановит, но эти ожидания мизерны. Так что асинхронность с такими функциями совершенно не подходит. Только потоки или процессы.

Comment: С другой стороны, если все три функции пишут в stdout, то может возникать ситуация, что функция A записала часть своих данных, а в след за ней B что то записала и потом только A дали дозаписать свои данные. У меня такое с stdout при выводе несколькими процессами случалось. В итоге пришлось все данные передавать одному процессу, что бы он в один поток их писал соблюдая последовательность. Так что любое распаралеливание трех функций выполняющих print может оказаться плохой идеей

Comment: @Mike, таки как создать с помощью чего будет лучше создать поток/процесс и как? Функции что были выше - к примеру приведены, в моих реалиях они постоянно читают память приложения и взаимодействуют с ним

Comment: Как вам выше сказал  Sergey Gornostaev все зависит от того, что же конкретно на самом деле выполняют эти функции. Какой ресурс они используют, cpu или сетевой ввод-вывод ? Работа с памятью - это явно cpu, тогда встает вопрос надо ли им видеть одну и ту же память или каждая из них что то делает исключительно в собственной памяти и их надо бы изолировать друг от друга (у потоков общая память, у процессов - раздельная)

Comment: @Mike, да, им нужно видеть одну и туже память, т.е - создать отдельные потоки

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html пишут
"In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once". Я правильно понимаю, что область применения потоков, в которых сам Python не может выполняться на нескольких ядрах, сремится к нулю?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос созданием новых потоков, как посоветовали в комментариях.